# Get text inside a <p> element inside span tag with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I have the following html part

```
<div>
<p class="wholesaletext"> Χονδρική Τιμή:&nbsp;<br/>
<span id="our_price_display" class="price" itemprop="price" content="9.9">
<p class="wholesaletext">9,90 €
</span> &chi;&omega;&rho;ί&sigmaf; &Phi;.&Pi;.&Alpha;
<meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="EUR" />                             
</p>
</p>
</div>
```

I am trying to get the text of `<p class=wholesaletext">` from the above with the following

```
Set price = ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("span")
Dim lnk As Variant        

 For Each lnk In price
    If lnk.className = "price" Then
        wks.Cells(i, "E").Value = lnk.innerText
        Exit For
    End If
 Next
```

I get nothing in cells.

I tried with

```
Set price = ie.Document.querySelector(".price .wholesaletext")
wks.Cells(i, "E").Value = price.innerText
```

I get nothing.

I tried

```
Set price = ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("p")
Dim lnk As Variant        

For Each lnk In price
    If lnk.className = "wholesale" Then
        wks.Cells(i, "E").Value = lnk.innerText
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

But it gets another text inside the html and not the price.

Comment: Try just .wholesaletext and have a wait before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better way to get the actual text is with the css class selector of `.wholesaletext`
So,

```
ie.document.querySelectorAll(".wholesaletext")
```

Then access text and text with price by index

```
ie.document.querySelectorAll(".wholesaletext").item(0).innerText
ie.document.querySelectorAll(".wholesaletext").item(1).innerText
```

CSS:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why not firstly use the `id` as opposed to the tag name and then go about it like this: `price = ie.Document.getElementByid("our_price_display")` and then to the price you would use `price.getAttribute("content")` so together it's be:

```
Set price = ie.Document.getElementByid("our_price_display")

wks.Cells(i, "E").Value = price.getAttribute("content")
```

Comment: It is working but when I try to convert it to currency I get 0,00€ why?

Comment: @Nikos probably because the content is a string datatype and you need a double to convert it to currency - this should fix that: `wks.Cells(i, "E").Value = CDbl(price.getAttribute("content"))`